# CDATE VBA gives out 12:00:00 AM instead of date

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert the date format of my cells as the csv format they are delivered in shows a date but excel doesn't recognize it as a date (it shows "Standard" as format and the dates are aligned on the left, hence not dates in excel).

[image]

```
    Dim lr11 As Integer
    Dim dates11 As Date
    
    lr11 = WS1.Cells(WS1.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row

    For dates11 = 2 To lr11
        WS1.Cells(dates11, 3).Value = CDate(Cells(dates11, 3).Value)
    Next dates11
```

The above code sometimes works in a Test Sub() but when used in my main Sub, I always get "12:00:00 AM" in all cells instead of dates.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You forgot the `WS1.` in front of `Cells`.

Comment: to clarify BigBen's comment, within the loop you need `WS1.Cells(dates11, 3).Value = CDate(WS1.Cells(dates11, 3).Value)`

Comment: `CDate` does not convert strings that look like a date into a date reliably. You need to split the date and use `DateSerial` to build a numeric date.

Comment: How exactly are you importing this CSV into Excel? There may be a way to avoid VBA entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If you have strings that look like dates in the format `DD.MM.YYYY` you can split them and create a numeric date using `DateSerial` like below:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function ConvertStringDDMMYYYYtoDate(ByVal InputString As String) As Date
    Dim RetVal As Date
    
    Dim Parts() As String
    Parts = Split(InputString, ".")
    
    If UBound(Parts) = 2 Then
        
        RetVal = DateSerial(Parts(2), Parts(1), Parts(0))
        If Not Format$(RetVal, "DD.MM.YYYY") = InputString Then
            MsgBox "Input String is not a real date", vbCritical
            RetVal = 0
        End If
    End If
    
    ConvertStringDDMMYYYYtoDate = RetVal
End Function
```

Then use it like

```
For dates11 = 2 To lr11
    WS1.Cells(dates11, 3).Value = ConvertStringDDMMYYYYtoDate(WS1.Cells(dates11, 3).Value)
    WS1.Cells(dates11, 3).NumberFormat = "DD.MM.YYYY"  ' format it however you like it to look like
Next dates11
```